# How to validate uniqueness of nested struct inside slice

Tags: go, validation, go-playground

I am using go-playground/validator

Does anyone know how to validate `Code` field for its uniqueness

```
type Product struct {
    Code      string `validate:"required"`
}

type UpdateValidation struct {
    Product    Product 
    Quantity   uint
}

type UpdateValidationSlice struct {
    SaleOrderItems []UpdateValidation `validate:"unique=Product,dive"` // unique=Product doesn't work
}
```

I have tried using `unique=Product` but it didn't work

Comment: Have you tried `validate:"unique,dive"`

Comment: I did, but didn't work either

Comment: Hi, the `validate:"unique,dive"` is work fine. See [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/iALPuBrzEd_D).

Comment: My bad, you re right, actually UpdateValidation struct has other field https://goplay.tools/snippet/rwHODUTHCYh that ls why it doesnt work for me